# Elements of specific order in $SL(2,q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $G = SL(2,q)$, the group of all invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices of determinant $1$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is odd.

(a) Determine the number of elements of order $2$ in $G$.

(b) Find an element of order $4$ in $G$.

Here are my thoughts so far:

(a) If an element $A$ of $G$ has order $2$, then $A^2 = I \Rightarrow A^2 - I = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ is an annihilating polynomial for $A$. Since the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide this annihilating polynomial, we have three possibilities for the minimal polynomial of $A$ : $m_A(x) = x-1, m_A(x) = x+1, m_A(x) = (x-1)(x+1)$. The first case is not possible; since a matrix satisfies its minimal polynomial, $m_A(x) = x-1$ would give that $A$ is the identity matrix in $SL(2,q)$, which has order $1$. In the second case, $A$ is the negative identity matrix, which *does* have order $2$ in $SL(2,q)$. The third case is not possible; in this case, the matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, and since the determinant is the product of eigenvalues, this would not give a determinant $1$ matrix over $F_q$.

Thus, I've got one element of order $2$ in $G$ so far, which is the negative identity matrix. The above process tells me that this is the *only* element of order $2$ in $G$. Is this correct ? I think the only other possibility is a scalar multiple $a \in \mathbb{F}_q$ of this, $-aI$, such that $a^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $q$) -- but I'm not sure how to count the number of these for general $q$.

(b) If an element $A$ of $G$ has order $4$, we get that $f(x) = x^4-1 = (x-1)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3)$ is an annihilating polynomial for $A$. The minimal polynomial cannot involve the second factor there, since we only have a $2 \times 2$ matrix -- thus, I believe the minimal polynomial must be $m_A(x) = x-1$. But, then this means $A$ is the identity matrix, which has order $1$. How can I find an element of order $4$ in $G$ ? My methods haven't brought any fruition in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Since $\mathbb{F}_q$ is finite field, it must have prime power order. So $q=p^n$ for some prime $p$. And $p$ must be odd, since you were given that $q$ is odd. Where you also given that $q$ is prime? It might make things easier if you were.

Comment: That's a great point -- I'd forgotten that every finite field has order $p^n$ for some prime $p$ and natural number $n$. Unfortunately, I wasn't given that $q$ is prime -- I had the same thought.

Comment: You say the minimal polynomial can't involve the second factor, but that isn't strictly true; it cannot *be* $1 + x + x^2 + x^3$, but it could *divide* it. What if $4 \mid q-1$, so $\mathbb{F}_q$ has a primitive 4th root of unity $i$? It might also help to compute the order of $\operatorname{SL}(2,q)$.

Comment: @Andre3000 embarassingly enough, I didn't go as far with the factorization as I could -- as pointed out by Andrew's (accepted) answer. Thanks for the comment !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** In part (b) we're asked to find an element of order $4$ in $G=SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$, where $q$ is odd. My original post contained a correct solution (i.e. I did find an element of order $4$). However, on the way to finding that element, I did say something that was incorrect. The mistake has been corrected below. Thanks go to the thoughtful reader who caught the mistake!

-- March 12th, 2022

**Part (a):** Your analysis for part (a) is correct. The minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, and since $A$ is $2\times2$, we must have either $m_A(x)=x-1$, $m_A(x)=x=1$, or $m_A(x)=(x-1)(x+1)$.

If $m_A(x)=x-1$, then since $A$ satisfies $m_A(x)$, we would have that $A-I=0$, which would imply that $A=I$. But since $I$ has order $1$, we can't have $m_A(x)=x-1$.

If $m_A(x)=(x-1)(x+1)$, then $A$ would have $1$, $-1$ for eigenvalues, so it wouldn't be an element of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. So it can't be that $m_A(x)=(x-1)(x+1)$.

If $m_A(x)=x+1$, then since $A$ satisfies $m_A(x)$, we would have that $A+I=0$, which implies that $A=-I$. Hence, there is exactly one element of order $2$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. (Note: we are implicitly using the fact that $q$ is odd, since if $q$ were even, then $1\equiv-1$).

You had asked if we could get other elements of order $2$ of the form $\alpha I$, for some scalar $\alpha$. If $\alpha I$ had order $2$ then $(\alpha I)^2=I$, which would imply that $\alpha$ satisfies the equation $\alpha^2=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Since $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a field, the only elements that satisfy this equation are $\pm1$.

**Part (b):** Let $A\in SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ be an element of order $4$. Then $A^4=I$, so $m_A(x)$ divides $x^4-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$.

Here's an idea for finding an element of order $4$: We've already shown that: **(1)** an element $A$ of $G=SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ has order $1$ iff $m_A(x)=x-1$; **(2)** an element $A$ of $G$ has order $2$ iff $m_A(x)=x+1$; and **(3)** there is no element $A$ of $G=SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ with $m_A(x)=(x-1)(x+1)$. So the idea is to see if we can find an element $A$ such that $m_A(x)$ divides $x^2+1$. In other words, let's try to find element $A$ with $A^2+I=0$.

Note: if an element $A$ of $G$ satisfied $A^2+I=0$, then it would also satisfy $A^4=I$. So it's order would have to be $1$, $2$, or $4$. On the other hand, an element $A$ with $A^2+I=0$ could not satisfy $A-I=0$ or $A+I=0$. So it's order could not be $1$ or $2$. So if $A^2+I=0$, then $A$ would have to be order $4$.

Finally, let's note that if we had an element $A$ of $G$ with $m_A(x)=x^2+1$, then from the rational canonical form, we would get that $A$ would be similar to $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ We can check that the above matrix does satisfy $A^2+I=0$, so it is, in fact, an element order $4$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Note: we are again assuming that $q$ is odd since otherwise we'd have $1\equiv-1$. Since all we had to do was find one element of order $4$, we are finished with part (b).

Comment: From the last paragraph it seems that it assumes $4 \mid q-3$, equivalently the polynomial $X^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_q[X]$.

Comment: You are correct!  I'm disappointed that I made that mistake, but I should be able to fix things pretty easily.  Thanks a lot for helping me write a better post!